# How to make nodejs code call csharp code in asp.net core (with JavascriptService) application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, node.js, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm using asp.net core for a simple web api server (with deepstream, actually).
While c# can call nodejs code flawlessly with NodeServices.InvokeExportAsync, when I try to pass Action/Func as parameter of NodeServices.InvokeExportAsync to nodejs, I get

```
System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Serializing delegates is not supported on this platform.)'
```

The error is quite self-explanatory, just wondering is there anyway to get around this? Maybe not passing delegate to nodejs, but through some other mechanism, to make calls from nodejs to csharp?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For callback functions from JS files.
Use  nodeServices.InvokeAsync

This [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37972.execute-javascript-code-from-asp-net-core-back-end-using-nodeservices.aspx) gives more info.

Comment: I know how to do it from c# to js, but how about the other way around? the callback in the example js is to pass result back, like a return...

Comment: You are trying to call a webapi from nodejs. It should be straight enough, as per error seem like you are trying to pass a JS delegate in webapi call and your expectation is now webapi will call this delegate - correct? If yes, the error is valid. Delegates don't serialize.

Comment: No...just the other way around, I was trying to pass C# delegate to js, hoping that js can callback to C# function, and get this error.

Comment: ok, this will not work. Delegate if can be serialized then can be done by binary serialization which cannot be read by other code. Going by your requirement either I would write an exe and pass parameter to JS to execute required function. In exe, search function by reflection and invoke or easy way use one technology JS or C#. My personal choice is latter.